# Gitlab pages and automatic certificate management using Let's Encrypt

Tags: ssl, gitlab

I guess that's a very simple task, but I can't manage to have SSL work on gitlab pages. Gitlab [pages documentation](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/pages/custom_domains_ssl_tls_certification/lets_encrypt_integration.md#troubleshooting) is too vague for me.

For example, when they say "Make sure your domain doesn't have an AAAA DNS record." does that mean the subdomain (say gitlab.mysite.com) doesn't have a AAAA record. Or does it mean my whole DNS configuration shouldn't have such a record?

Also if that's the later, how can I manage to make this work?

Maybe someone has a source to a good tutorial for this because I really struggle finding simple information (not assuming any prior knowledge about SSL/gitlab).

Comment: Are you self-hosting GitLab or are you on GitLab.com?

Comment: Ah sorry, yes it's on gitlab.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went through the whole process beginning to end and set up a GitLab Pages website on a custom domain with a Let's Encrypt certificate -- it worked like a charm.

I had to:

a) set up a TXT record to verify domain ownership, and

b) add an A record to point at the GitLab Pages IP address (since my domain DNS management provider didn't allow me to set up a domain-level CNAME)

After this, GitLab went and fetched a Let's Encrypt certificate for my Pages web site.

I didn't *have* a AAAA record, so that didn't come into the picture.

As per GitLab Pages documentation section [GitLab Pages integration with Let's Encrypt](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/pages/custom_domains_ssl_tls_certification/lets_encrypt_integration.md#gitlab-pages-integration-with-lets-encrypt),

**Caution**: This feature covers only certificates for **custom domains**

[Issue 3342](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/3342) is open to add support for sub-domains.

If you are still having trouble, let me know, I'd be happy to help with this.

Comment: I followed the same path, but it doesn't work for me. (ownership verification wasn't a problem for me). About **custom domains**, what is this?

Comment: Ah, I managed to access the pages at a strange location, something that look like : `https://<project-name>.gitlab.io/-/dev/server/-/jobs/531242071/artifacts/public/index.html` but I still get a 404 when trying to reach `https://<project-name>.gitlab.io/index.html` (which I guess should be the latest version of the produced file). I also still have the SSL problem …

Comment: Okay.  **A custom domain** is your own domain.

Comment: Could you try hitting http://<username>.gitlab.io/<project-name>/  ? For example, my username is "atsaloli" and my example project is "gitlab-pages-example", and I can access it at https://atsaloli.gitlab.io/gitlab-pages-example/

Comment: I think I understand what happened, it seems like there is a deployment phase (from gitlab) that do something (no idea what) with my html files. It also seems like this is only triggered on master (I have been lucky with trying this, but it worked). It doesn't solved the SSL thing tho.

Comment: Okay, excellent progress!  Can you access your Pages site via your custom domain without SSL?

Comment: Yes I can over http.

Comment: Very good.  Now that we've fulfilled the Requirements (https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/pages/custom_domains_ssl_tls_certification/lets_encrypt_integration.md#requirements), let's revisit the section "Enabling Let's Encrypt integration for your custom domain" (https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/pages/custom_domains_ssl_tls_certification/lets_encrypt_integration.md#enabling-lets-encrypt-integration-for-your-custom-domain).  Could you please go through it again and let me know what it says?

Comment: Same as before, it says "GitLab is obtaining a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate for this domain. This process can take some time. Please try again later."

Comment: Ah, this time it worked, wut. I haven't changed anything. Ok. Thanks :)

Comment: That would probably be interesting to sum up what was the problem here just in case other people have the same kind of issue.

Comment: There were a few things we had to work through.  BTW, you mentioned it worked from "master" but not from other branches -- the vendor documentation states, "Remember that GitLab Pages are by default branch/tag agnostic and their deployment relies solely on what you specify in `.gitlab-ci.yml`" (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/introduction.html#gitlab-ciyml-for-a-repository-where-theres-also-actual-code)  We cleared up what a "custom domain" is, fulfilled the Requirements and then the pieces just fell into place. Pleasure working with you!